# Error SSL NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID Even SSL Not Expired Yet

Tags: ssl, https, digital-ocean, cloudflare, namecheap

My website get traffic drop recently. I found that my user cannot access my website when their computer in wrong set of time. However, they can open other website as usual.

The error said "NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID" in google chrome and "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead" in firefox. So, I assumed that the problem is the SSL. Previously I use free ssl from Cloudflare, thinked that its because its free then the error appeared, I the purchased for Dedicated SSL form Cloudflare. But, I keep get the same Error.

Is there is a solution for this situastion? 
Changing the user computer time its not my solution here, because other website working just fine.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> I found that my user cannot access my website when their computer in wrong set of time.

The expiration of the certificate is checked against the local time of the system. If the local time is wrong the check might fail even if the certificate is not really expired yet.

If it fails depends on how wrong the local time is compared to the expiration time in the certificate, i.e. it might be so wrong that some certificates look expired while others are not yet expired. Some sites use more short-lived certificates  and thus are more likely to run into this kind of problems.  For example Let's Encrypt certificates are only valid for 3 month, while other CA issue certificates for a year or even longer. And of course sites which only use HTTP instead of HTTPS don't have this problem since no certificates are involved in the first place.

> Changing the user computer time its not my solution here, because other website working just fine.

There is nothing you can do against this from the server side. And while some other sites work just fine for the moment it is very likely that there are some sites apart from yours which will not work too. So the problem is not restricted to your site only.